# Macbook turns on but screen is dead or completely dark

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen

My Macbook Pro's screen just blinked and went dark.

When I turn the computer on, the fan turn on and runs but the screen is dark.
I tried all the option and tricks but nothing is works. I rebooted several times still the screen is black but the fan is running.

I'm not sure if the backlight is on or not, but at a first impression it's either on and black or there's no backlight and no image being drawn.

What can I do short of sending it in for repair?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has an excellent process to triage macs that don’t boot all the way.

If you hold the option key or boot to internet recovery, you should see things on the screen even if there is no drive present, no OS present so you can know you need a repair if you can’t even see internet recovery like here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156

In the end, you will have a working Mac again - possibly reinstalling the OS or erasing and then reinstalling or you take it in for service since there is a hardware issue.

Start here and ask a follow on question with exactly where your troubleshooting led you.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204267

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201295 says the SMC covers Mac ..

> Responding to the display lid opening and closing on Mac notebooks

You can try resetting the SMC.

> Try this first:
>
> - Choose Apple menu > Shut Down and wait for your Mac to shut down.
> - Press and hold the power button for 10 seconds.
> - Release the power button, then wait a few seconds.
> - Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
>
> If that doesn't resolve the issue, follow these steps:
>
> - Choose Apple menu > Shut Down and wait for your Mac to shut down.
> - Press and hold the right Shift key, the left Option key, and the left Control key for 7 seconds. Your Mac might turn on and show the
>     Apple logo on its display. Keep holding those keys while you also
>     press and hold the power button for another 7 seconds. If your Mac
>     turned on when you first pressed the keys, it turns off at this point.
> - Release all three keys and the power button, then wait a few seconds.
> - Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.

[Boot hangs on grey screen (even when booting from USB drive with fresh OS X install)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120507/boot-hangs-on-grey-screen-even-when-booting-from-usb-drive-with-fresh-os-x-inst) is also informative if you're a victim of the GPU issue.